# Create object property with two optional conditions

Tags: javascript, parameters, conditional-statements, object-property

**What do I want?**

I want to create an object property what capitalizes every word in a string, optional replaces underscores with spaces and/or lowercase the string first. I want to set the options by two parameters:

*First parameter true?*

Then replace all underscores with whitespace.

*Second parameter true?*

Then lowercase the complete string first.

**What do I have so far working?**

*replace underscore with space first and then capitalize all words:*

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(underscore){
return (underscore ? this.replace(/\_/g, " ") : this).replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
}

var strUnderscoreFalse = "javaSCrIPT replace_First_underderscore with whitespace_false";

//replace underscore first = false
console.log(strUnderscoreFalse.capitalize());

var strUnderscoreTrue = "javaSCrIPT replace_First_underderscore with whitespace_true";

//replace underscore first = true
console.log(strUnderscoreTrue.capitalize(true));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3tZjE/)

*lowercase string first and then capitalize all words:*

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(lower){
return (lower ? this.toLowerCase() : this).replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
}

var strLcaseFalse = "javaSCrIPT lowercase First false";

//lowercase first = false
console.log(strLcaseFalse.capitalize());

var strLcaseTrue = "javaSCrIPT lowercase First true";

//lowercase first = true
console.log(strLcaseTrue.capitalize(true));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nvHWx/)

**What are my questions?**

- This is the first time I'm trying to create an object property with this condition notice. How can I join this two options into my object property function that I only have to set the two parameters?

For example:

```
//replace underscore first = true and lowercase first = true
console.log(str.capitalize(true , true));

//replace underscore first = false and lowercase first = true
console.log(str.capitalize(false , true));
```

- What is anyway the name of writing the condition with syntax notation like **"?"** and **":"**?

Comment: The `…?…:…` operator is the “conditional operator”. In this case, you should use a few `if` statements to be non-confusing.

Comment: Don't call that thing a property. It's a *method*!

Comment: @ Bergi Thanks for this comment, the better i know how to call *things* the easier it is to search for explanations, examples, tutorials etc..

Comment: @false alright, than I will use if statements instead of conditional operators. Because I'm curious, isn't it even possible with conditional operators?

Comment: @Dinizworld: It is, but you have to add one for every combination (without variables); it’s not pleasant.